# Scary copy/paste always gets my attention on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

It always give me a shock when i try to copy / paste a **single** file. Is there any good reason to show "Copying 1,014 items from ..."

[image]

Comment: because you're copying 1,014 items and not one?

Comment: You are probably copy/pasting a directory not a file.

Comment: btw, this is the copy dialog from Windows 8 and not Windows 7

Comment: Yeah it's not windows 7 my bad. Going to change it.